# Create templates from attributes for categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I want to make something as a template for requested attributes for products by categories. For example let's have category named shirts, I would like every product from this category to have color and size attributes. What I want is when I go to the attribute menu, while I'm creating new product, those attributes to be already there, and just type their value.

Comment: Hey Lamper, welcome to WordPress development. Please update your question and tell us: What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck now?

Answer (score -1):

You might find this link useful for creating custom fields in product page:

http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please try to add at least a synopsis of the linked content. What value do these links have as soon as they go 404?